# WP 4.4. responsive images browser choosing the "wrong" one

Tags: images, responsive, customization

I'm glad that WP 4.4. ships with a built-in responsive image feature. But I'm not that happy with it.

I have set up some custom image sizes in my `functions.php`:

```
add_image_size('post-thumbnails', 600, 600, true);
add_image_size('news-large', 1024, false);
add_image_size('news-small', 500, false);
add_image_size('3-col', 500, 375, true);
add_image_size('presscutting', 600, 850, true);
add_image_size('medium-large', 768, false); // just added today for devices support
add_image_size('full-feature-image', 2000, false);
add_image_size('gallery-image', 800, 600, true);
```

As I figured, images that aren't cropped (cropping set to `false`) are added to the `srcset`. An image is output in the frontend like (line breaks added for better readability):

```
<img width="2000" height="1335"
src="http://mywebsite.com/cms/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/image-2000x1335.jpg" 
class="attachment-full-feature-image size-full-feature-image"
alt="asdf"
srcset="
http://mywebsite.com/cms/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/image-300x200.jpg 300w, 
http://mywebsite.com/cms/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/image-768x513.jpg 768w, 
http://mywebsite.com/cms/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/image-1024x683.jpg 1024w, 
http://mywebsite.com/cms/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/image-500x334.jpg 500w" 
sizes="(max-width: 2000px) 100vw, 2000px">
```

But now my problem: On my screen, only the images specified with 1024px width are shown, although it hast a 1600px screen resolution. So all the images look blurry.

**How can i make WP and/or my browser use the 2kpx image instead?**
Would I have to add new image sizes for, let's say 1280px, 1440px, 1600px, 1968px? Or is there a simpler way of telling WP / the browser to use the larger image instead of showing a blurry and way too small version?

Comment: Can you please try this out with the correct way to use `add_image_size`? You always set the `width` argument to false - this should be an integer (third argument).

Comment: Ok, done that and added height-value of 9999. Resized thumbnails. No avail.

Comment: The default of the `max_srcset_image_width` filter is 1600.

Comment: Good to know @birgire - but that doesn't help much.
How do I change it (there seems to be no documentation yet) - and will a change solve my problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Concerning documentation there is this blog post on the Make Blog:

[Responsive Images in WordPress 4.4](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/11/10/responsive-images-in-wordpress-4-4/)

To increase the 1600px limit mentioned in the comments try this:

```
add_filter('max_srcset_image_width', function($max_srcset_image_width, $size_array){
    return 2000;
}, 10, 2);
```

Finally as already mentioned you should fix your calls to [`add_image_size`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/)

> <strike>add_image_size('news-large', 1024, false);</strike>

needs to be

```
add_image_size('news-large', 1024, 0, false);
```

Comment: Thank you. I've set the height to 9999 - does it make any difference?
I'll try it out.

Comment: Thank you, that made it work. Although it is basically the same answer as [this one](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/211453/29055) and actually I prefer *named* functions - I accepted yours because you were first :-)

Comment: I think this might be the answer I need, but I don't know what value `$size_array` should have.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same issue by adding an extra size to the `srcset` with a filter function that you can add in your `functions.php`:

```
function filter_max_srcset( $max_width, $size_array ) {
    if ( $size_array[0] === 1800 ) {
        $max_width = 1800;
    }
    return $max_width;
}
add_filter( 'max_srcset_image_width', 'filter_max_srcset', 10, 2 );
```